# Can't tweet an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tweets

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    forTweet = TRUE;
    switch(buttonIndex)
    {
            case 0:
            {
                TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

                // Set the initial tweet text. See the framework for additional properties that can be set.
                NSMutableString * twitterString = [displayString mutableCopy];
                [twitterString appendString: @" #LoviOtvet"];

                [tweetViewController setInitialText: twitterString];

                UIImage * imageAnswer = [self getImageFromURL: [self strToUrlConverter]];
                UIImage * imageLogo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"image.png"];

                [tweetViewController addImage: [self mergeImage:imageAnswer withImage:imageLogo strength:1]];


                break;
            }
```

I added . No errors, but not working.
Facebook and saving to device working. Tweeting not. Why not?

Comment: Is `mergeImage:withImage:strength` actually returning an image?

Comment: - (UIImage * ) mergeImage: (UIImage *) imageA withImage:  (UIImage *) imageB strength: (float) strength;

Comment: I think Stephen means is returned object really an image (not nil for example)

Comment: Yes, @igoris is correct; that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: oh, yes it returns normal image without errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
UIImage * imageLogo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"image.png"];
```

For this method, you would need to need to provide a file path, not a name. You have two choices:

UIImage * imageLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:]

or (for a file in the bundle):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage * imageLogo = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: No, in original code there state path. But here I changed it, it was not a good choice.

Comment: OK - then add a log or assert() after you set "UIImage * imageLogo" - want to bet its nil ???